# Visual Studio's automatic indention

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on someone else's C# source files in Visual Studio 2015. 
Here is how I use indention in the IDE:

- When I hit return key to create a new line, the IDE automatically add indents to the new line.
- Some other times, I select a region of multiple lines, and click menu "Edit -> Advanced -> increase/decrease line indent".

That creates a mixed use of tabs and four space combinations in the same source file, probably because the original author of the source files used different way to indent lines in their Visual Studio than I do via the IDE.

I wonder how I can make it consistent to use either tabs or four spaces for indenting every line, instead of mixing them in the same source files?

I followed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165330(v=vs.90).aspx, but couldn't find out if there is a setting for me to solve my problem.

Comment: Press CTRL-K-D and will auto indent the full file

Comment: is it same as hit the return key?

Comment: That's kind of an old version of that document. Here's a more recent one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sffa753.aspx

Comment: "When I hit return key to create a new line, the IDE automatically add indents to the new line." this is not actually the case: ever since Visual Studio 2010 the IDE will *not* add whitespace indentation to empty lines (it will only "virtually" indent the caret), it only adds indentation characters (tabs or spaces, depending on your settings) if you press something other than Return on a line.

Answer (score 3):

Simple press the following combination (while holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

This will automaticly reformat your code.

Answer (score 3):

Try pressing

> CTRL-K-D

It will properly indent all the code in your file

You can change the indent size, and a bunch of other things

Please check this link

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnstudents/2014/02/10/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-formatting-your-code/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has an Adaptive Formatting behavior which the Editor heuristically determines if the current file should use Tabs or Spaces for indentation.
You can turn this behavior off by going to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced` and uncheck “Use adaptive formatting”.